# Is it possible to use a common resource in an non-themed view?

Tags: orchardcms

I am using orchard cms v 1.4 and developing some site content that is stand alone and does not use the standard theme. I would like to use some of the resources already declared in manifest files on the non-themed views. However they only render when I apply a theme to the controller or the specific view.

In my view I am including the following:

```
@{
    Script.Require("jQuery").AtHead();
}
```

This only functions as expected when I include: `[Themed]`
as an attribute on my controller.

Any idea's on how to get this to work without creating a full theme for my stand alone pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2012/10/20/writing-an-unthemed-view-while-still-using-orchard-shapes-and-helpers.aspx

What's important is that you use a shape as the model. Themed or not doesn't matter then.

Comment: I checked the article and would like to confirm, the shape, MyShapeName should not be created in C# neither as Razor View. The Index View will be displayed. Even if I add styles and JavaScript using Orchard helpers they are not displayed.